# Call Result Returning Wrong from Proxy Contract

Tags: ropsten, proxy-contracts

I published my proxy (AdminUpgradeabilityProxy) and logic contract to Ropsten Test network.

But my call result is returning wrong value through the my proxy contract. For example I call to totalsupply() function in logic contract (I use proxy contract address) then the call result is wrong is that:

```
{
    "totalSupply": "3963877391197344453575983046348115674221700746820753546331534351508065746944"
}
```

(The result must be '0'... :( )

and then I call the owner() function in logic contract through the proxy and  I'm getting wrong result again

The Contract Owner call result:

```
{
    "owner": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

whereas, I saw the owner and ProxyAdmin address is correctly set when I publish the contracts to Ropsten network.

what is my fault? why the result returning as a wrong value :(

And my deploy script :

```
await deployer.deploy(logic); const instance = await logic.deployed();
await instance.initialize("0x5f1007A94861275Ca739D1B16ac2fdb673bf2002");
await deployer.deploy(AdminUpgradeability, logic.address, "0x5f1007A94861275Ca739D1B16ac2fdb673bf2002");
```

thank you

Comment: Are we supposed to guess your code, or even the state of your contract on ropsten??? Please publish all the relevant information, i.e., your code, and the address of your contract on ropsten. Also, if you haven't verified your contract on etherscan, then please do that, so we can read it via etherscan.

Comment: please add your smart contract so that people can help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works as expected from remix.

- totalSupply: 0
- owner: `0x0000..00`
- name: '' (empty string)
- symbol: '' (empty string)

Logic address might have been initialized but it doesn't matter, since storage will be read from proxy address.

The error might be how are you invoking the proxy.

---

The problem is in the deployment script

```
await deployer.deploy(logic);

// Logic contract will be used for the bytecode
// it is not necessary to initialize
// const instance = await logic.deployed();
// await instance.initialize("deployerAccount");

await deployer.deploy(AdminUpgradeability, logic.address, "deployerAccount");
// const instanceAdminUpgrade = await AdminUpgradeability.deployed();

// To use logic from proxy we need an instance of logic
// that points to AdminUpgradeability.address
const instanceAdminUpgrade = await logic.at(AdminUpgradeability.address);

// Initialize proxied instance
await instanceAdminUpgrade.initialize("deployerAccount");
```

Comment: @YaseminCırt It seems you are erroneously initializing logic contract. You have to initialize the proxy contract. Add the deployment script to the question so we can check what it is wrong with it.

Comment: @YaseminCırt It is better to edit your question and add the script there.

Comment: thank you @Ismael the problem solved with your advise for this stage.